# Setting the screen position of a program

Tags: vbscript

How do I set the position of a third party program,using vbscript,to always display at a specific position on the screen?

Comment: WMI offers an API to do it but in my tests, I can only get `cmd.exe` to work, not Notepad, not MSPaint.  https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4285

Answer (score 2):

VBScript and Windows Script Host don't have this functionality out of the box, so the short answer is "You can't".

The long answer is: If you really need to do this, you can use a third-party tool for this purpose, such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/AutoIt/). You could also write a custom utility (in C++, C# with PInvoke etc) that will utilize the appropriate Windows API functions ([`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx), [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx) etc) and call it from your script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible using VBScript.  As Helen mentioned, it could be done with AutoIt or in C++, C#, etc.

Using AutoIt, you could either write a script that always ran, and checked to see if the Window of the third party app exists, and then move it to the location you desire... Or better, create a launcher script to start the third party application and place it at the exact location.  If you can't install AutoIt on all the pc's this will be running on, you can also compile the script to a stand alone exe.